# Uploading datetimeoffset column with only hour as timezone to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datetimeoffset

I have a `timestamp` column having values like the following in my database:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:58.538-05
2017-01-01 00:16:58.54-05
```

The data type is `varchar` since `datetime`, `datetime2` formats did not work. I need to convert this column to datetime format now. I just discovered about `datetimeoffset`. :(

However, the conversion still does not work as is, and I get an error. datetimeoffset wants to see at least `-05:0` not only `-05`.

```
DECLARE @datevar datetimeoffset = '2017-01-01 00:00:58.538-05';  
SELECT @datevar
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What can be to solve this? Worst case scenario I tend use `python` to preprocess each file to add `:0` at the end of each value, and then save the file, and then bulk upload every file in the folder at the end. However, each file has ~30 million rows, and there are 365 of them per year. So I really do not want to do that.

Again, the data is already uploaded, an easy and FAST way to do this would be appreciated. There are about 8 billion rows in the table now, so I do not know whether this can be done using SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `:00` appending in sql itself

```
SELECT Cast(dates + ':00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET),
       dates
FROM   (VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:00:58.538-05'),
               ('2017-01-01 00:16:58.54-05')) tc (dates)
```

considering none of your dates has minutes part of timezone. If some dates has minutes part then it needs to be handled differently

In your table it should be something like

```
SELECT Cast(datecolumn + ':00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET),
       datecolumn 
FROM   Yourtable
```

to update the table

```
update t set yourcol = Cast(yourcol + ':00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET)
FROM   Yourtable
```

Then alter the table datatype to `datetimeoffset` and make sure you upload data with time part in offset

Comment: Can you add an answer where I can work with column rather than individual values? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, this does the trick. But how do I save it back to the table? And I need two options here: 1 - To add the datetimeoffset values into a new column, 2 - To overwrite the current column.

Comment: Thanks. I found it myself as well after digging for hour. Here is what I did: alter table table_name add timestamp2 datetimeoffset;
go;

update table_name
set timestamp2 = 
( cast(timestamp + ':00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET) );